# Function to show custom content on marker popup

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet, var, marker

Before I was able to show in the PopUp the content of "pname" inside "icons.js", I managed to show that using this function. Now I added two more fields "dropname" and "dropicon", that I want to show under "pname". But something is wrong in my code. I don't know if the syntax is wrong or what, I know I am missing something in that function.
Anyone can help me?
My full code that uses that function is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiRgOuodGYyr0Rsl6PZk?p=preview

```
function showResourcesByName(name) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.resources.length; i++) {
        var resName = markers.resources[i].name;

        if (resName == name) {
            var resIcon = icons.resources[i].icon;
            var resSize = icons.resources[i].size;
            var resPname = icons.resources[i].pname;
            var resDropName = icons.resources[i].dropname;
            var resDropIcon = icons.resources[i].dropicon;

            alert (resDropName.lenght);

            var popupContent = '<span class="markername">'+resPname+'</span><span class="drop">Drops:</span><div class="dropimgs">';

            var popupContentDrops;

                for (var dropindex = 0; dropindex < icons.resources[i].dropname.lenght; dropindex++) {

                    popupContentDrops += '<img src="'+resDropIcon[dropindex]+'"><span class="dropimgtext">'+resDropName[dropindex]+'</span>';

                }

            popupContent += popupContentDrops + '</div>';

            var customIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: resIcon,
                iconSize: resSize, // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [resSize[0]/2, resSize[1]/2], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [2, -resSize[1]/2] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            });

            for (var j = 0; j < markers.resources[i].coords.length; j++) {
                var x = markers.resources[i].coords[j].x;
                var y = markers.resources[i].coords[j].y;

                marker = L.marker([y, x], {icon: customIcon});
                marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(popupContent);
                $(marker._icon).addClass(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

1. you should replace `lenght` with `length` (multiple places)
2. no `dropname` property in your `icons.resources` objects, but there is `name` property; maybe you should change it to `icons.resources[i].name` (multiple places)
3. no `dropicon` property in your `icons.resources` objects, but there is `icon` property; maybe you should change it to `icons.resources[i].icon` (maybe multiple places)

Works here - http://plnkr.co/edit/8xgDc8zZYc6FVR6unAtf?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

1. I changed that. typing mistakes.

2. There are a property in icons.js called dropname and dropicon, its under: AIBorServer

`{
   "name": "AIBorServer",
   "icon": "icons/bor.png",
   "size": [32,21],
   "pname": "Bor",
   "dropname" : ["Raw Steak", "Animal Fat","Leather"],
   "dropicon": ["http://findicons.com/files/icons/2360/spirit20/20/marker.png","http://findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/marker_rounded_yellow.png","http://findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/marker_rounded_red.png"]
  }`

I want to show that inside the popup.

Comment: You are iterating 28 resources while have only one of them with `dropname` and `dropicon` properties. I made the code accomodate that, so now an image `Bor` shows some pins. But I can't get you properties that are not there. http://plnkr.co/edit/8xgDc8zZYc6FVR6unAtf?p=preview.